# Applet not Initialized in applet viewer(2D Game)

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a basic 2D game, following a YouTube series. I'm trying to go out of my way to make it more neater (by adding Classes that have individual jobs)

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/joelwmale/org.joelmale.game.darkshrine)

I'm trying to communicate between: Window (should just generate the window/applet, Loop (the main of the program), and Movement (which updates the player's coordinates and img animation).

I just completed adding everything, but when i try and run the program
It says "APPLET NOT INTIALIZED" and Spams:

```
ava.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.security.AccessControlContext.optimize(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.getContext(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Panel.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Panel.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.applet.Applet.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.joelmale.game.darkshrine.backend.Loop.<init>(Loop.java:8)
at org.joelmale.game.darkshrine.backend.Movement.<init>(Movement.java:28)
```

Is there something i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop while (true){ in your Loop class is checking nothing and is always true. And could be causing it to overflow your stack

Comment: The true loop has always been there and it worked fine until i decided to split the classes up into a more organized fashion... The code now runs fine with my version, but displays nothing. and does nothing. Just a blank white window.

Comment: well your image background is unused at the moment

Comment: Where should i call it? I updated the Github, i tried to put it at the end of init, but it didn't work... I'm stuck :(

Comment: I don't know why you don't call graphics.drawImage(background, 854, 480, this); in init(){ and see if it displays

Comment: and I'd move the backgound import to the start of your class

Comment: Doing  graphics.drawImage(background, 854, 480, this);

Doesn't draw anything. The program runs fine with no errors, but even with that straight after "graphics = offScreen.getGraphics():
it doesn't work.